# ASP.NET: Reading list of values from web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net

in a cs file I have a IF function like this>

```
If (myValue == 'AA' || myValue == 'BB' || myValue == 'CC')
{
DoThis()
}
```

But now and then I have to add some more conditions:  myValue == 'DD' and so on.

Is not possible insert the new values (and All values)
in the web.config
and read from there instead of modify the code?

For example, in my web.config file I can have something like this:

```
<appSettings>
     <add key="AA" value="AA"/>
     <add key="BB" value="BB"/>
     <add key="CC" value="CC"/>
     <add key="DD" value="DD"/>
</appSettings>
```

and in the code I should have something like:

IF mySearchString is present in the list from web.config, THEN call DoThis() method

Thank you in advance.

Luis

Comment: Everything is possible. What is the exact problem? You do not know, how to read data from web.config; or there is some another issue?

Comment: Basically I should read a list of strings from the web.config, and create a Foreach that loops for all the strings and calls the DoThis().
So I need only to deploy the web.config without recompile the entire website. 
This would be my idea.

Comment: @Ciupaz Yes, that is a fine idea. I would advise to write some code and post it as a new question if you have issues.

Comment: I've added some more code in the question, so is more clear, I hope.

Comment: web.config changes cause a recompile... if you want not to recompile each time you add/substract from that list I suggest to use a .txt with some JSON config parameters inside it

Comment: You don't need to rebuild if there are changes to web.config as long as it's saved. Does this work for you?
string variable= WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["variable"];

Comment: Well, my fault, you didn't need to recompile, but iis will restart the AppPool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
var appSets = 
ConfigurationManager.GetSection("appSettings") as NameValueCollection;
   
  if (appSets["AA"]=="AA" || appSets["BB"]=="BB") do something
```

or you can iterate using Linq or foreach

```
    foreach (var item in appSets.Keys)
    {
      var key = item.ToString();
      var value = appSets[key];
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

First create a key in web.config with comma separated value as below.

```
<appSettings>
     <add key="Categories" value="AA,BB,CC,DD"/>
</appSettings>
```

Then access the variable and split it.

```dotnet
var categories = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Categories"].Split(',');
        
if(categories.Contains(myValue)){
    DoThis()
}
```

Comment: I can use a Foreach and call DoThis() for every strings, right?

Comment: Yes you can do that.

Comment: foreach (string value in categories)
{
    DoThis():
}

could be fine?

Comment: That is fine @Ciupaz

Comment: Note that changes the logic though as you could be calling DoThis() multiple times instead of once.

Comment: Right, I have to take care of the Search criteria of the user.

Comment: @Ciupaz please mark it as accepted answer so if anyone comes across they can make use of the solution.